# What shape is an irregular cylinder flattened out?

Tags: geometry

A cylinder flattened out is a rectangle (ignore the top and bottom faces).

But what about a cylinder where the top face is smaller than the bottom face...what shape is that flattened out? (again ignoring the faces themselves)

See here for an image: [image]

I'm asking because I'd like to 3d print a planar thing that can be folded into this shape.

I can take a piece of paper and roll it up into a cylinder but can't for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: What you're asking about is not called a cylinder.  It is called a conical frustum.  And when unfolded, it produces an annular section,  which is what you get when you draw two concentric circles and take a (polar) section (angular part, like pizza) of that.

Comment: This [tool](https://www.geogebra.org/m/g6hteh6d) helps.

Comment: Thank you to both of you!